# Problems using the sum of geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$2^0 + 2^1 + 2^ 2 + 2^3+...+2^{n+1}$

According to the general formula, the above sequence can be summed by $\frac{r^{n+1}-1} {r-1}$.

If I plug the parameters from the above sequence I don't get the same answer and I don't understand why since it's supposed to be the general recursive formula.

However if i use $\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1} - \frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$, then the results seem to follow the above sequence.

Can someone explain please, thanks

Comment: You used the wrong exponent: $$\sum_{i=0}^n x^i = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1},$$ so $$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} x^i = \frac{x^{n+2}-1}{x-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

The general formula for $\sum_{i=0}^n r^i$ is $\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$, when $r \neq 1$. Now in your case you want the sum till $n+1$ so it will be $\frac{2^{n+2}-1}{2-1}=4 \cdot 2^n-1$

In fact the second formula you use it's the sum of the first $n$ terms minus the sum of the first $n-1$ terms, so just the $n$-th term, i.e. $2^n$